# What is the criteria for entering ranked matches?

Tags: smite

I have almost reached rank 30, which unlocks ranked games in the menu.

I have been told that there are additional requirements.  Namely I need to master at least 18 gods.  This isn't really a problem, as I have around 40 mastered.  However, I do not own 18 mastered gods, as I simply master some of the gods on the free rotation each week.

Do I also need to *own* 18 mastered gods in order to play ranked?

Does *owning* also include gods on the free rotation?  For example, if I own 16 gods, all mastered, will 2 gods on the current free rotation (also currently mastered) allow me to play ranked games?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No, Gods on the free rotation do not count

If you click on Play, and then click on Ranked, you'll be brought to the Ranked play screen where there are three different play modes: Conquest, Duel, and Joust. You can click on the "More Info" question mark, which will list the requirements. For instance, here are the requirements for Conquest (which you seem to refer to in your question):

[image]

It says rather clearly that players must have a minimum of 18 OWNED gods at Mastery Level 1 or higher. This makes sense, since it would seem pretty ridiculous to qualify for ranked and earn a rating one week, and then be unqualified for rank play the next week because the God rotation happens to coincide with Gods you already own.

Having said that, I do believe you can play any Gods you have access to that you have at mastery 1 or higher, including those in the free rotation, once you qualify for Ranked play.

Comment: Just a couple of things I noticed when I finally reached level 30... firstly, there is no More Info on the Xbox One version (well, from what I can see).  I'm guessing this refers to the PC version.  Secondly, I was playing on an all access god weekend (so had 18 mastered gods but only 16 owned).  I was unable to play Ranked Conquest (game said I needed 18 mastered gods) but was able to play Ranked Duel and Ranked Joust.

Comment: Ranked Duel and Joust have lower requirements, so that is exactly what should have happened. Yes, my answer is from the perspective of PC since that's what I play Smite on. It would take some really strong evidence to convince me that the ranking system somehow works differently between platforms, though.